# How do I open a text notification from lock screen on S4?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have given up on my iPhone 5 and now I have the Samsung Galaxy S 4. So far I love it with one exception:

I get the notifications in the lock screen and the preview in the lock screen, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to just open text message directly from lock screen in one action.

I have a couple friends with S3's and they can open text notifications with a swipe from their lock screen and they can't even figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know there must be a way to swipe the text notification on lock screen that will bring me straight to text message.

Answer (score 1):

From [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41234395&postcount=18):

> Just swipe the message box down to open the messaging app directly,
>   same for missed calls.

I think the message box here refers to a transparent message box that appears when you click on the message in the lockscreen.